# Relation between spectral norm and entries of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, matrix-norms, spectral-norm

I have a matrix $\textbf{A}\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ with singular values $\left\{\sigma_i\right\}_{i=1}^n$.  How do I show that
$$\sigma_1>\max_{i,j}|\textbf{A}_{ij}|,$$
where $\sigma_1$ is the maximum singular value?

Here is my attempt. Starting with the Frobenius norm $\|\textbf{A}\|_F$,
\begin{align}
\|\textbf{A}\|_F&=\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^n|\textbf{A}_{ij}|^2}\\
&=\sqrt{\text{tr}\left\{\textbf{A}^H\textbf{A}\right\}}\\
&=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n\sigma_i^2}\\
&\le\sqrt{n\sigma_1^2}
\end{align}
and so
$\sqrt{n\sigma_1^2}\ge\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^n|\textbf{A}_{ij}|^2}$.

How can I proceed?

Comment: This won't work, as $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\|A\|_F$ can be smaller than $\max_{i,j}|a_{ij}|$. An easier approach is to use the property that $\sigma_1(A)=\max_{\|x\|_2=1}\|Ax\|_2$. By the way, the strict inequality sign in the problem statement shall be replaced by "$\ge$".

Comment: @user1551 Do you lower bound $\sigma_1$ by choosing $\textbf{x}$ with 1 in the entry corresponding to the column of  $\textbf{A}$ with the greatest entry?

Comment: Yes, that will do the trick.